# Eclipse/Win7 - Scrolling in Content Assist with mouse without focus

Tags: eclipse, windows-7, scroll, mouse, content-assist

Recently switched from Linux to Windows for development in Eclipse Indigo SR1.   In Linux, if I Ctrl-Space'd to open a Content Assist window, I could immediately start scrolling with the mouse wheel (with the cursor over the Content Assist window of course).

Now, in Windows 7, if I try to scroll in the same way the Content Assist window goes away, and whatever editor I have open is scrolled instead.

If I first press Tab to give focus to the Content Assist window, the mouse wheel scrolling works as expected, but I'd much rather it behaved as it did for me on Linux, rather than retrain myself to press Tab every time.

Is there a way to make the mouse work this way with Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer that appears to work.   It's a little dated but seems to still do the trick.

http://divby0.blogspot.com/2007/04/focus-follows-mouse.html

Dropped this jar in the eclipse plugins folder and restarted.  At first I thought it didn't work, but later I noticed there is a little X button added to your toolbar that you need to toggle.  Scrolling seems to work properly now.

Comment: After testing it for a day or so, it's not perfect - a few things aren't *quite* right when the plugin is enabled.